# unknow Error in Making AutoEncoder using Keras

Tags: autoencoder, tf.keras

```
from tensorflow.keras import metrics
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Reshape, Input, Dense,Flatten, Reshape
import numpy as np
```

↑ import packages

```
from keras.datasets import mnist

(x_train, _), (x_test, _) = mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.
x_train = x_train.reshape(60000,28,28,-1)
x_test = x_test.reshape(10000,28,28,-1)
```

↑ loading data, mnist.

```
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_train = x_train[:,:,:,]
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_train
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (len(x_train), 28, 28, 1))  
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (len(x_test), 28, 28, 1))  

input_img = Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))
```

↑ handling data and make input layer.

```
# encoder
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(10, activation='relu')(x)
encoded = Dense(1, activation='softmax')(x)

encoder = Model(input_img, encoded, name = "encoder")
```

↑ encoder part. I'm trying to compress mnist image to 1 value.

```
# decoder
decoder_input= Input((1))
decoder = Dense(64, activation='relu')(decoder_input)
x=  Dense(64, activation='relu')(decoder)
x=  Dense(98, activation='relu')(x)
x=  Dense(196, activation='relu')(x)
x=  Dense(392, activation='relu')(x)
x=  Dense(784, activation='relu')(x)
decoded =  Reshape([28,28,1])(x)

decoder = Model(decoder_input, decoded, name='decoder')
```

↑ and decoder part. making mnist image from a value.

```
auto_input = Input(shape=(28,28,1))
encoded = encoder(auto_input)
decoded = decoder(encoded)

auto_encoder = Model(auto_input, decoded)
auto_encoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')
```

↑ connect encoder&decoder.

```
auto_encoder.fit(
    x_train, 
    x_train,
    epochs=64,
    batch_size=128,
    shuffle=True,
    validation_data=(x_test, x_test)              
)
```

↑ and trying to learn my AutoEncoder but it fails.

error message is below.

> UnknownError:  Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably
>   because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning
>   log message was printed above.

I searched lots of time in google, but I still cannot get clue.
I made right shape of data, right shape of outputs, but error shows.

what is the Cause of the problem?

Comment: What GPU are you using?

Comment: rtx 2070s. But I made another conv-Autoencoder successfully without any problem. So the problem is my code, not hardware or enviroment, i guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RTX 2070 GPUs require memory growth to be set to True in recent versions of CUDA and CuDNN.

Add these lines to the top of the file you run:

```
import tensorflow as tf
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
config = tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
```

Comment: still not sure what is the problem but Now I know that depending on the hardware, I may need to put special sentences.